# Next.js public/images not showing in vercel production build

Tags: vercel, nextjs-image

I have a Next.js app I am deploying to Vercel. When I dev locally I see the images, but when I push to Vercel and check the site, the images have a 404. I have a public/images folder where I have the images right in the folder, and the code I reference the image like this

```
<Image
  src="/images/logo.jpg"
  alt="logo"
  width="70"
  height="70" />
```

Both locally and in production, if I look at the image source they are the same `src="/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Flogo.jpg&w=1920&q=75"` but I get a 404 in production. What could be causing the image to show up in localhost but not in the Vercel production build?

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint" }
```

Folder Structure

```
components
pages
public/images/
```

Localhost images working

```
http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Flogo.jpg&w=1920&q=75
```

Vercel Production Images not working

```
https://mohammadrahi-portfolio.vercel.app/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Flogo.jpg&w=1920&q=75
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone else ran into the same problem when images not showing in `Vercel production build`, well, Vercel accepts `.svg` images, and the path simply should be starting from the base Url (`/`), static files, like images, should be under a folder called public in your root directory, and files inside public can then be referenced in your code starting from the base URL (`/`)

e.g `<img src="/imgs/logo.svg" alt="My Logo" />`

I ran into the exact same issue and fixed it by this solution, hope it helps you as well

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it was because I was rewriting `/images` in my middleware.
It looks like Vercel handles images on a `/images` URL path even though locally they are in directory `/public/images`.

So if you have a `middleware.ts` file that has code like

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // some matcher that includes `/images`
  ],
};
```

And you are doing any rewrites then it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this code in Nextconfig file :

```
 const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
     loader: "akamai",
     path: "/",
    },
 };
```

it sets starting path to root.